# 'SortedDict' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, django, sorteddictionary, askbot

After deploying AskBot I observe an unusual error:

> AttributeError at /settings/QA_SITE_SETTINGS/
>      'SortedDict' object has no attribute 'insert'

This is the result of the following code:

```
langs_dict = SortedDict(django_settings.LANGUAGES)
default_code = django_settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
default_name = langs_dict[default_code]
langs_dict.insert(0, default_code, default_name)
```

According to [Django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict), `SortedDict` seems to have `insert` method.

Any idea?

<sub>Here is the complete [error page](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/amirgon/4cee430a181104568643/raw/dc61d7c118fcf7bacd757edf54dd8b7642aa96ad/AttributeError%2520at%2520_settings_QA_SITE_SETTINGS_.html).

Related: [AskBot bug](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/issues/517).</sub>

Comment: From the wiki page you linked: «SortedDict is deprecated as of Django 1.7 and will be removed in Django 1.9. Use [​collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.» Herein lies the fix, I suppose.

Comment: @9000 Django version is 1.7.10, therefore should still be supported although deprecated. Do you think it's a Django bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug in Django. The `inserted` method was deprecated then removed. The problem is in AskBot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SortedDict.insert`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/utils/) method was deprecated in Django 1.5, and removed in Django 1.7. The [wiki page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict) you linked to was out of date, so I removed the mention of the `insert` method from there.

`SortedDict` itself is deprecated in Django 1.7, and will be removed in Django 1.9.

Now that Django only supports Python 2.7+, the correct fix is to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `SortedDict`.